# What is the singular for an octadic?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

As I understand the octadic is 8 of something.

In relation to sections, what would be a single section called in the octadic?

The comparison I draw from is the quartile, each 'section' being a quarter.

Is there a similar case for the octadic?

To further explain, what would a shaded section in this picture be referred to as? For a quarter, I would refer to this area as a quartile.

[image: image of circle divided into eight]

*Edit: I am aware it may be possible (maybe not) to use 'the eighth'. However, it just doesn't feel correct.*

Comment: Could you tell me where you found your definition of octennial? Because the [normal definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=octennial&oq=octennial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.911j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) of octennial means that a single "section" in an octennial is called a **year**.

Comment: But in general, on _eighth_ part of a whole is called one _eighth_.  A quartile _is_ a quarter, a quarter is not _part_ of a quartile. If you have a collection of eight items, each part is an **item**. I suggest you edit your question to clarify what you are actually asking for :)

Comment: @oerkelens you are correct my mistake this should have been " octadic

Comment: My dictionary agrees with @oerkelens': an octennial is a set of eight years. I think the word you're after is an **[octet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/octet?q=octet)**: "A group of eight people or things".

Comment: But one part of a set of eight is **one**, or is my math so wrong now?

Comment: An eighth of a year is one and a half months. Unless of course one of those months is February. Then it gets crazy.

Comment: I have updated the question with a very non colorful picture to highlight :) I feel stupid already though for getting the initial work wrong!

Comment: I think the whole "set of eight things" caused a lot of confusion. From your edit I now seem to understand you are looking for the equivalent of _quartile_ when there are 8 pieces which would be _octile_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your picture, I wonder if [**octile**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octile) is not simply what you are looking for?

Quarter => quartile
Eighth => octile
Tenth => decile
Hundredth => percentile

Comment: I will use it anyway.. its purely for code commenting on an array.. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 5):

For the specific diagram you give, an eighth-part is an *[octant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octant)*, using the following senses of the word.

> 1. The eighth part of a circle; an arc of 45 degrees.
> 2. (geometry): The eighth part of a disc; a sector of 45 degrees; half a quadrant.

A fourth of the diagram is a *[quadrant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadrant)*, in the sense “One fourth of a circle or disc; a sector with an angle of 90°”.  (More commonly, *quadrant* has the sense  “One of the four sections made by dividing an area with two perpendicular lines” or of being one of the regions of the Cartesian plane that are bounded by the x-axis and y-axis; the  “first quadrant” being the region where x>0, y>0;  “second quadrant” where x>0, y<0; etc.)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head for the use case. Thank you for such a concise answer.

Comment: +1, "octant" is the term I've seen used in context where such a term is needed (e.g. with various [line drawing algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm), where the first step is often determining which octant the direction of the line falls in).

Answer (score 4):

A single section of 8 would be an eighth (notice the extra "H" at the end):

[eighth  [eytth, eyth]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eighth)

> adjective
>
> 1. next after the seventh.
> 2. being one of eight equal parts. noun
> 3. an eighth part, especially of one (⅛).

But as oerkelens says, a single of an [Octennial](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/octennial) is a year.

Comment: This makes perfect logical sense, i was just hoping for a fancier word i suppose! Thank You!

Comment: "a single of an Octennial is a year". This doesn't make sense to me. If you have AN Octennial, it's singular. There is only one Octennial. A year then would be one eighth Octennials and is not singular anymore(with respect to Octennials). Years are also Octiles of Octennials.

Comment: There's two meanings of Octennial. One is something with recurs every eight years, and the second meaning is something which lasts eight years. One eighth of the second definition would be a year.

Answer (score 0):

**Suboctuple**:  [Sub*oc"tave\, Suboctuple \Sub*oc"tu*ple\, a. Containing one part of eight; having the ratio of one to eight. --Bp. Wilkins.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suboctave)

Answer (score 0):

**Singleton**:  [A single object, especially one of a group.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/singleton)

This definition has the added benefit of not being tied to the number eight.  For instance, it works equally well as a single item belonging to a group of 27 items.