# What is an eighth of a circle called?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

In my code, I have a variable that stores the number of segments per one eighth of a circle. I wonder if there is a synonym for *eighth of a circle*, because `segmentsPerEighthOfCircle` is a little lengthy. In [another thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/168991/326904) users suggest [octile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octile) and [octant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octant). But I can't get the difference. Will you clarify the difference and the correct usage?

Comment: A quarter: quadrant. An eighth: [octant](https://www.lexico.com/definition/octant). I have never heard of a 'quadrile' or 'octile' but looking it up [octile](https://www.lexico.com/definition/octile) is used in statistics (not geometry) and it does not mean an eighth of a circle.

Comment: Well, you could always use "slice", once you'd established it's precise meaning.  A slice of a pie is typically 1/6th or 1/8th.

Comment: Also called a _semi-square_, as an aspect (angular separation) in astrology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Octant” is the right word, but be aware most people won’t be familiar with it.

The difference between “octant” (or “quadrant”) and “octile” (or “quartile”) is that -ile is used for order/rank whereas -ant is used for position.

For instance, a point might be in the upper-right quadrant on a graph (X and Y both positive), whereas your score on a test might be in the top quartile (the best 1/4).

Comment: Note that Merriam-Webster defines octant as "any of the eight parts into which a space is divided by three coordinate planes" (which is basically a quadrant extended into three dimensions), but not as an eighth of a circle. So there is _some_ room for confusion here that one should be aware of before using octant.